# Undefined variable in __construct()... but I did define it

Tags: php, oop

I've written the following piece of code:

```
Class stackOverflowExample {

    private $hash;
    private $cookie_file;

    public function __construct(){

        @session_start();

        if(isset($_SESSION['gc_hash'])){
                $this->$hash = $_SESSION['gc_hash'];
        }else{
                $this->$hash = md5(time());
                $_SESSION['gc_hash'] = $this->$hash;
        }

        $this->$cookie_file = "./cookies/{$this->$hash}.txt";

    }

}
```

But I'm getting this error

> Notice: Undefined variable: hash in
>   /var/www/gausie/gc/GeoCaching.Class.php on line 21
>
> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in
>   /var/www/gausie/gc/GeoCaching.Class.php on line 21

In the original code, line 21 refers to `$this->$hash = $_SESSION['gc_hash'];`.

I can't see why this is happening, although I'm new to OO PHP. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

just replace `$this->$hash` by `$this->hash`

`$this->$hash` means variable with name equals to variable `$hash` value

Comment: RiaD's point being that you only require the `$` before the `this` and nowhere else when using PHP's object notation.

Comment: Correct :) - `$this->$hash` would reference a variable named like the content of `$hash` that is placed inside the class. So for it to work you would need to declare `$hash = 'hash';` once done that it would work like that too, but that's not really the correct way of doing it. See the answer for how to do that :)

Comment: Ah. I feel silly. Upvotes. EDIT: I realise this isn't Reddit.